# Data scraper in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This was my first attempt at scraping approximately 1800 open datasets from the web. On the first go-around it takes approximately 1 hour to complete. Subsequent iterations only take 4 seconds. I'm guessing there are much better ways to implement the logic that I did with regard to filename structure and overall efficiency.

```
def scraper(url,downloadDirectory):
    start = time.time()

    baseUrl = r"{some_url}"


    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    table = bsObj.findAll("table")[0]
    links = table.findAll("a")

    count = 0
    broken_links = []
    for link in links:
        try:
            count += 1
            link = str(link).split("\"")
            if len(link) > 1:
                print(link)
                link = link[1]
                linkBreak = link.split("_")
            else:
                if link[0] == "<a></a>":
                    print("Skipping")
                    continue
                else:
                    print(link)
                    linkBreak = link.split("_")

            title = re.findall(r"[\w']+",str(linkBreak))[9].strip("'")
            if title == "nyc":
                title = re.findall(r"[\w']+",str(linkBreak))[10].strip("'")
            print("# " + str(count), "Title: " + str(title))
            dir_path = os.path.join(downloadDirectory,title) 
            if os.path.isdir(dir_path) == False:
                print("Creating directory: " + str(os.path.join(downloadDirectory,title)))
                os.mkdir(dir_path)

            file_path = urllib.parse.urljoin(baseUrl,link)
            print("File Path: " + str(file_path), "\n" + "Directory Path: " + str(dir_path))
            print("Split array and length: ", linkBreak, len(linkBreak))
            if len(linkBreak) == 1:
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,str(linkBreak[0]).split("/")[7])):
                    print("Skipping")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,str(linkBreak[0]).split("/")[7])))
                    urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,str(linkBreak[0]).split("/")[7]))
            elif len(linkBreak) == 2:
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1])):
                    print("Skipping")
                    continue
                elif str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1])).endswith(".zip") == False:
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1] + ".zip")):
                        print("Skipping")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1] + ".zip")))
                        urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1] + ".zip"))
                else:
                    print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1])))
                    urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[1]))
            elif len(linkBreak) == 3:
                if "?" in linkBreak[2]:
                    linkBreak[2] = linkBreak[2].split("?", 1)[0]
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])):
                        print("Skipping")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])))
                        urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2]))
                if title == "sidewalkcafe":
                    linkBreak[2] = str(linkBreak[1]) + str(linkBreak[2])
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + linkBreak[2])):
                        print("Skipping")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + linkBreak[2])))
                        urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + linkBreak[2]))
                else:
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])):
                        print("Skipping")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])))
                        urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2]))
            elif len(linkBreak) == 4:
                if "?" in linkBreak[3]:
                    linkBreak[3] = linkBreak[3].split("?",1)[0]
                    linkBreak[2] = str(linkBreak[2]) + "_" + str(linkBreak[3])
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])):
                        print("Skipping")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])))
                        urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2]))
                else:
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])):
                        print("Skipping")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Result: " + str(os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2])))
                        urlretrieve(file_path,os.path.join(dir_path,title + "_" + linkBreak[2]))
        except HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 404:
                print(e)
                print(count,"__________")
                broken_links.append([count,title,link])
                continue
            else:
                raise

    end = time.time()
    fp = os.path.join(downloadDirectory,"BrokenLinks.txt")
    file = open(fp,"w+")
    for link in broken_links:
        file.write(str(link) + "\n")
    file.write(str(datetime.now()))
    file.close()

    return("Script completed in: " + str(end - start) + " seconds.")

archURL = {some_url}
archDownloadDirectory = {some_localpath}

scraper(archURL,archDownloadDirectory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Whereas your code might work now, I strongly recommend using `requests` instead of `urlopen`. Requests is awesome, and makes a lot of complicated stuff simple, especially for web scrapers.
- I believe `BeautifulSoup` will complain unless you pass another parameter to its constructor, `'html.parser'`.
- You have everything in one function. This is very difficult to read, understand and debug. I recommend subdividing this into smaller functions called from your top-level function.
- You have a bunch of repeated code - for instance, your `if isfile` logic. Again, factor this out into functions where possible.
- You do not need to call `str` on `file_path`. It's already a str.
- Rather than calling `file.close()`, you can put this in a `with` block. Read about them here - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with
- There's a better way to do your printing. This:

`print("File Path: " + str(file_path), "\n" + "Directory Path: " + str(dir_path))`

Is better written as:

```
print('File Path: %s' % file_path)
print('Directory Path: %s' % dir_path)
```

You get the idea. It's easier to read if you have one `print` statement per line. Also,

`title + "_" + linkBreak[2]`

is more easily read as

`'%s_%s' % (title, linkBreak[2])`

With that expression in particular, you reuse it many times throughout the code, so it should be assigned to a variable.

Here:

```
linkBreak[3] = linkBreak[3].split("?",1)[0]
```

You're dropping the query parameters from the URL. You probably shouldn't be doing this parsing yourself. You should be calling `urlparse`.

- `downloadDirectory`, pythonically, should use snake_case, i.e. `download_dir`. Same with other identifiers like `archDownloadDirectory`

Comment: (Installing and) using `'lxml'` instead of `'html.parser'` will give you a nice speedboost (but will add an external dependency).

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the suggestions!